# Playframework and Twitter Streaming API

Tags: scala, twitter, playframework, twitter-streaming-api, playframework-2.5

How to read response data from Twitter Streaming API - POST statuses/filter ?
I have established connection and I receive 200 status code, but I don't know how to read tweets. I just want to println tweets as they coming.

```
ws.url(url)
.sign(OAuthCalculator(consumerKey, requestToken))
.withMethod("POST")
.stream()
.map { response =>
  if(response.headers.status == 200)
    println(response.body)
}
```

EDIT: I found this solution

```
ws.url(url)
.sign(OAuthCalculator(consumerKey, requestToken))
.withMethod("POST")
.stream()
.map { response => 
  if(response.headers.status == 200){
    response.body
      .scan("")((acc, curr) => if (acc.contains("\r\n")) curr.utf8String else acc + curr.utf8String)
      .filter(_.contains("\r\n"))
      .map(json => Try(parse(json).extract[Tweet]))
      .runForeach {
        case Success(tweet) =>
          println("-----")
          println(tweet.text)
        case Failure(e) =>
          println("-----")
          println(e.getStackTrace)
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The body of the response for a streaming WS request is an Akka Streams [`Source`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4/?_ga=1.123705931.1172875281.1456351629#akka.stream.scaladsl.Source) of bytes. Since Twitter Api responses are newline delimited (usually) you can use [`Framing.delimiter`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4/?_ga=1.123705931.1172875281.1456351629#akka.stream.scaladsl.Framing) to split them up into byte chunks, parse the chunks to JSON, and do what you want with them. Something like this should work:

```
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Framing
import scala.util.{Success, Try}
import akka.util.ByteString
import play.api.libs.json.{JsSuccess, Json, Reads}
import play.api.libs.oauth.{ConsumerKey, OAuthCalculator, RequestToken}

case class Tweet(id: Long, text: String)
object Tweet {
  implicit val reads: Reads[Tweet] = Json.reads[Tweet]
}

def twitter = Action.async { implicit request =>
  ws.url("https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?track=Rio2016")
      .sign(OAuthCalculator(consumerKey, requestToken))
      .withMethod("POST")
      .stream().flatMap { response =>
    response.body
      // Split up the byte stream into delimited chunks. Note
      // that the chunks are quite big
      .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString.fromString("\n"), 20000))
      // Parse the chunks into JSON, and then to a Tweet.
      // A better parsing strategy would be to account for all
      // the different possible responses, but here we just
      // collect those that match a Tweet.
      .map(bytes => Try(Json.parse(bytes.toArray).validate[Tweet]))
      .collect {
        case Success(JsSuccess(tweet, _)) => tweet.text
      }
      // Print out each chunk
      .runForeach(println).map { _ =>
        Ok("done")
    }
  }
}
```

Note: to materialize the stream you'll need to inject an implicit `Materializer` into your controller.

Comment: Thanks for explanation

Comment: Is it possible later close connection? I'm planning to have multiple request for tracking different words and I want in some future time close specific connection?

Comment: Have a look at a [Dynamic Stream Handling](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.8/scala/stream/stream-dynamic.html) in the Akka docs. One idea: create a shared kill switch, then add it to the stream with `source.via(killSwitch.flow)`. Running `shutdown()` on the killswitch should close the connection.

Comment: So I have add my WS stream request to Source(Stream(request)).via(sharedKillSwitch.flow) but when I run shutdown() on killswitch connection is still opened

Answer (score 3):

calling `stream()` gives you back a `Future[StreamedResponse]`. you'll then have to use akka idioms to convert the `ByteString` chunks within that. something like:

```
val stream = ws.url(url)
  .sign(OAuthCalculator(consumerKey, requestToken))
  .withMethod("POST")
  .stream()

stream flatMap { res =>
  res.body.runWith(Sink.foreach[ByteString] { bytes =>
    println(bytes.utf8String)
  })
}
```

note that i didn't test the code above (but it's based off of the streaming response section of https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWS plus the sink description from http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.2/scala/stream/stream-flows-and-basics.html)

also note that this will print each chunk on its own line, and i'm not sure if the twitter API gives back complete json blobs per chunk. you may need to use a `Sink.fold` if you want to accumulate chunks before printing them.