# Reactive web applications read twitter stream Play Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, stream, enumerate

I am trying to follow the Twitter stream example of the Manning's [Reactive Web applications](https://www.manning.com/books/reactive-web-applications)
The book is based on PlayFramework 2.5, however I would like to use a newer version of the framework, because why not.
The book example uses a third party library https://github.com/jroper/play-iteratees-extras which doesnt seems to work with newer Play versions. The example uses this library to encode the stream received from twitter and to create a iteratee of a Json objects. My question is, is there any way to bypass this library with the existing Scala / Play API?

The piece of code is the next:

```
val jsonStream: Enumerator[JsObject] =
    enumerator &>
    Encoding.decode() &>
    Enumeratee.grouped(JsonIteratees.jsSimpleObject)

val loggingIteratee = Iteratee.foreach[JsObject] { value =>
    Logger.info(value.toString)
}
```

I tried to not to use the decode part and to create a Iteratee of JsObject, however I get an error regarding the iteratees:

> object Iteratee does not take type parameters.

Any hint on to how bypass this library?

Comment: Iteratees are deprecated in favor of Akka-Stream as you can see in the [migration guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/StreamsMigration25)

Answer (score 1):

I had to do the following to follow the book to a T. I understand it is old stuff but just want to get the initial concepts then go to newer processes.

1. `scalaVersion := "2.10.7"` in `build.sbt`
2. `sbt.version=0.13.13` in `build.properties`
3. `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.10")` in `plugins.sbt`

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with the same problem and after some searching found [the solution using Akka Streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39054030/playframework-and-twitter-streaming-api). Hope that helps.